# ASP.NET Core OData Atompub formatter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

I am trying to format an ASP.NET Core OData response to `Atom+xml` to retain backward compatibility.

Here is the code I tried but I still have no luck. Is there a way I can format response in `atom+xml` ?

```
builder.services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions (o =>{
 o.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
});
```

The ASP.NET Core code is clearing the headers in the call and adding the new header value and asp.net code is format is getting changed to atom xml.

```
this.Request.Headers.Clear()
this.Request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/atom+xml")
```

Comment: You're applying all these changes to MVC, not OData

Comment: [XML formatting is already enabled](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/blob/fd4107e74b267e06efa67663072c3dd7de9bfbb7/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/Formatter/ODataOutputFormatterFactory.cs#L31). Did the client forget to request XML perhaps?